# How to count no of elements before a given element in std::set

Tags: c++, stdset

I want to find no of elements present in set before the lower bound of an given element,I thought of using pointer arithmetic with std::set::iterators since they behave like pointer, here is what I tried:

```
set<int>q;
set<int>::iterator curr;
set<int>::iterator strt;
l = num.size();
q.insert(num[l-1]);
strt = q.begin();
temp = 1;
int x;
for(int i=l-2;i>=0;i--)
{
    curr = q.lower_bound(num[i]);
    if(curr == q.end())
        stats.push_back({temp,0});
    else
    {
        x = curr-strt;//ERROR
        stats.push_back({x,temp-x});
    }
    q.insert(num[i]);
    temp++;
}
```

is there is any way find no of elements present in set before the lower bound of an given element?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to iterate through the set from the beginning to the point you've found to count the number of elements. There's a [library function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) for that:

```
x = std::distance(strt, curr);
```

Arithmetic like `curr-strt` is only defined for random access iterators, where the calculation can be done in constant time. Functions like `distance` will work for more general iterator types, but might be slow if the iterator doesn't directly support that operator.

Comment: That a `O(n)`, is there any other method with lesser time complexity or is there any more suitable container?

Comment: @Sab: Depending on what else you're doing, a sorted array/vector might be better. You can use `std::lower_bound` etc. to search in logarithmic time, and find iterator distances in constant time. Maintaining the sorted order might need more work.

Comment: @MikeSeymour It's important to note that "You'll have to iterate through the set from the beginning to the point you've found" is not a property of balanced trees in general, just STL trees in particular. You might want to see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Using [data structure augmentation](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap15.htm), it's possible to do dynamic order statistics in logarithmic time.

I've written once a [libstdc++ extension for this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/pb_ds/), and later on mad a [python version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Banyan/0.1.5).